# Is it possible to open and select a file in explorer at browser test of Laravel Dusk?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel-5.3, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk2

Im new to Laravel5.
I want to browser test with Laravel Dusk.
I already have a Java code but can not find the way to code in Laravel Dusk.

```
public void test() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.freepdfconvert.com/pdf-word");
    driver.findElement(By.id("clientUpload")).click();
    driver.switchTo()
            .activeElement()
            .sendKeys(
                    "/home/likewise-open/GLOBAL/123/Documents/filename.txt");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("convertButton"));
```

The code below does not work for me because the app I want to test is mainly used Javascript, so I need to upload files through an explorer.

```
$browser->attach()->...
```